# If I have a String of tweets (json), can I load into Twitter4j Tweet[]?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Lets say I have a String

```
 String jsonTweets;
```

and I just get this using regular HttpClient request.  How can I convert this String into Tweet classes somehow using TwitterAPI ME or Twitter4j?

Note:  I am not going to use TwittrAPI ME or Twitter4j to create the jsonTweets String. I already have it and just want to use the API to have the equivalent java classes.  Tweet.java.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataObjectFactory#createStatus() to instantiate Status object from raw json string.
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/json/DataObjectFactory.html#createStatus(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include those whole libraries if you just want a Tweet class and some methods to parse them.  Create your own Tweet class, instantiate a JSONObject passing your json string to the constructor, and use the getString and getXYZ methods to populate your Tweet class.

If you want to use Twitter4j, doing a quick search through their online JavaDoc led me to this:

http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/json/DataObjectFactory.html#tweetConstructor

It looks like it takes in a JSON string of standard tweet data from Twitter's api and returns their Tweet object.